# $0=1$, or I have done something wrong.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, fake-proofs

$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\int1dx \frac{1}{x}-\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}\int1dx\right)dx=1+\int\frac{1}{x}dx \Leftrightarrow 0=1$$

Comment: Remember, indefinite integrals are only defined up to an additive constant.

Comment: $+C{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: 1 *does* equal 0 .... plus a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes! This is one of the integrals you should always remember! Recall that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\ln(x)\right)=\frac{1}{x}$$

hence $$\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln(|x|) + Constant$$

Comment: @ZacharySelk, my lecturer would kill me for that, thanks ahah

Answer (score 1):

When $f$ is continuous the "$=$" sign in $g(x)=\int f(x)dx$  is not literally "equals". It means that $g$ is an anti-derivative of $f.$ But $g+C$ is also an anti-derivative of $f$ for any constant $C.$